# Hotkeys missing on new SQL Server Management Studio install

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I've just replaced SSMS Express 2005 with 2008, and my favourite hotkeys, like CTRL+N for a new query window, and CTRL+O to open a file in a query window, are missing.  How can I restore them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in SSMS 2008. The first time I clicked File->New->Query with current connection, no CTRL+N hotkey was visible in the menu item, and that key combo did nothing. Ever since I clicked that menu option, the hotkey is now visible against it and the combo works normally.